# Get the very next node with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm sure it's pretty easy, but I just can get it to work.

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="row forWidget"></div>
<div class="droppable"></div>
```

I have the first element in my jQuery object.

```
$widget = $('div.row');
```

And I want to `.find()` the element div.droppable from there.

How do I achieve this?
I thought it would be `.next()`, but it seems to only match real siblings.

Comment: What do you mean "real siblings"?

Comment: And they are not "real" siblings?

Comment: Why aren't they "real" siblings?

Comment: Ahhh! I tried to get the node before it's been loaded into the DOM -.- Yeah, pretty stupid :D Anyways. I thought "real siblings" would mean that they contain same attributes, classes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serach for the `.next()`

var next = $('div.row').next();

http://api.jquery.com/next/

From jQuery site

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.row').next();`

[Documentation for next.](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use
. Next('div') if you are looking specifically for a div

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
$('div.row').next('.droppable');
```

this way, you will find your droppable div even if other div are inserted between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

In your HTML:

```
<div class="widget">
   <div class="row forWidget"></div>
   <div class="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

In your JS:

```
$('.row').parents('.widget').find('.droppable')
```